# Fivestar - filter by number of votes

Tags: 7, views, rating

I want to filter a view that shows nodes sorted by rating. I would like to filter it to only show nodes with at least 5 votes.
I added the relationship for "vote results - number of votes". 
When I add the filter it doesn't give me an option for "greater than":

[image]

Any ideas how to fix that?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When i added the **Vote results: Value type** field for output. It shown like **percent** or **points** so how can we filter the varchar field type with number behavior. 
I think  you should filter by **Vote results: Value** not **Vote results: Value type**

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! I got confused by the label "The value of an individual cast vote.", that's why I hadn't even tried that one ;-)

Comment: Ok that's fine. :)